# C# Disable NET Framework errors

Tags: c#, message

Is it possible to disable all errors in C# winform application?
I wan't to hide/disable that messages:
[image]

Comment: Sure, it's possible to catch pretty much all exceptions and ignore them. The real question here is why would you want to do that?

Comment: @Saragis because I don't know where is the bad code :(

Comment: You can ask Visual Studio to break when an exception is thrown. That'd be a real good start...

Comment: @Dewagg That would just amount to a empty `catch { }` block.  However as Saragis said it would be better to deal with or at the very least log the errors somewhere.

Comment: Debug -> Exceptions -> Check 'Thrown' on the first two.  Press OK, re-run your application

Comment: What info does the details button provide? It will point you to the error in your code. You have a simple object not set error.

Comment: object reference exceptions usually point to bugs in the application. Why ignore those ?

Answer (score 0):

See the [AppDomain.UnhandledException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception(v=vs.110).aspx) event.  Just assign a handler as the first bit of code in your application and you can do whatever you want with unhandled errors.

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += (sender, args) =>
{
   //handler code
};
```

However, see the first comment to your post...are you SURE you want to do that?  You never know what kind of errors you might be swallowing at that point.

Comment: Would probably be best to attach to Application.ThreadException as well, since it's WinForms.